# Is it possible to protect an App Engine application with IAP while having a few public URLs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-iap

I have an Google App Engine Standard (Python 3) application that I've secured behind Google IAP. This works great! But now I need a handful of web hook urls to be public, so other services can hit them, like SendGrid. Is there a solution to this that I am not seeing?

Comment: It seems it is not available to designate a "public" URL in an IAP-protected App Engine app now and there is no intent on supporting the feature.

For App Engine apps, individual versions and services can have different access policies applied. If you have already set IAP as per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart), you can separate your App Engine app in different services and provide granular access.

Also check out [this link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access) for more information about managing access to resources.

Answer (score 2):

As Ahmad suggested, the solution is to have a separate App Engine *service* that is publicly accessible.